# How can I remove newline characters from being entered into a C# DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a C# DataGridView in production into which users sometimes paste strings. Some percentage of the time, these strings contain newline characters (carriage returns), which foul up processing further on down the line. I would like to automatically remove these characters from the strings as they are entered or pasted.

I am looking at the CellParsing event as a solution to the problem, but do not want to foul up all my other processing (it's a fairly complex grid). Is this the appropriate solution to the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you adding rows?  Manually?  Or via data source?

Comment: I'm not adding rows in this case, just editing existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

If your data grid view is bound to a data source, then the only way to do what you want is to remove the unwanted new lines in your data set, i.e. in your data mapper/translation layer.

If you're adding rows manually, you can replace the unwanted new lines in your `.Add` loop one-by-one using `.Replace`:

```
const string NewlineReplacement = " ";

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(col1Value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, NewlineReplacement),
                       col2Value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, NewlineReplacement));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChange` event.

the event will raise **after** any cell change by the user.

please see the example i wrote that also shows how to extract the column and row of the requested cell.

```
private void datagridview1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        int rowNum = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int colNum = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        // do here what ever you wish: Replace, Trim, etc...
         dataGridView1.Rows[rowNum].Cells[colNum].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNum].Cells[colNum].Value + "...";
    }
```

also, dont forget to add handler for you DataGridView:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += datagridview1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
```